# WCF REST API Partial update of a record

Tags: c#, wpf, rest

I am writing a WCF Rest API that provides CRUD functionality to an entity say **Student**. Here is how it is defined:

```
class Student
{
  Guid Id;
  string Name;
  string LastName;
  string Age;
  DateTime DOB; 
}
```

My service contract is something like this:

```
class StudentService
{
  [WebInvoke(Method = "POST")]
  public void Add(Student student)
  {...}

  [WebInvoke(Method = "PUT")]
  public void Update(Student student)
  {...}

  [WebGet()]
  public void Get(string Id)
  {...}

}
```

Now the thing is that while updating a student record the client may not provide complete data. For e.g. it may provide Id and DOB but no name and LastName. Id being mandatory field. I need to know what could be the best approach/design in such a case?

I can fetch the existing record from db and perform a compare on both then update as necessary. The problem with this approach is that I have no way of knowing if a user actually wants to update a field to null. And then again, comparison does not seem a neat design. Any ideas?

Comment: I may be missing something on your system design but an update implies that the client has already a recent student record that it is working from. You should have a "GET" method in your API that retrieves a student record.  The user would update the information in the current record and send back the complete record. So if the user only changed the DOB it would still have the current Id, Name, etc...  No need to do a compare unless you are performing some kind of change tracking.

Comment: @KevinJunghans , Yes I have GET Method too. (Updated the question too). But the thing is that since I will not be consuming the service I simply can't force the client to call a GET before updating. Its kind of a feature where update will work by updating only the fields that you provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going through various strategies of handling this kind of thing  I sort of implemented what was described in the answer to this question: [Only update some properties on an EF entity that are not set to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9000702/only-update-some-properties-on-an-ef-entity-that-are-not-set-to-null).

In a nutshell I am tracking which properties were set during desrialization and then updating only those properties.

Answer (score 0):

Send all the values in sp, then while updating records write case statement for checking null
You can check isnull in Update Statement, so when parameter is null then  update them with their own values

like

Update Student
set Name = case when isnull(@Name,'') ='' then Name else @Name end
where Id = 1127871

Comment: Well I am using Entity framework and don't plan to use Stored procedures. I am thinking of handling this thing before it gets to the database.

Comment: Then what you are doing is fine!!